# SSRS 2005 - How do I find the value of a cell 1 column over and 2 rows up?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, offset

I am trying to find the value of a cell 1 column over and 2 rows up using something like excels offset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the value of a cell if the cell has a name using the following

ReportItems!YourCellValueGoesHere.Value

Answer (score 0):

You can't: there is no column or row collection as such to use.

In addition, matrix controls, grouping, and merged cells would further complicate this